# Conditional Segue in Swift

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift, segue

I want to do a "connexion" button in my app. And when you tap on it, it will open a new page if you have correct login.

But, I read that we can't undo a segue, I suppose I need to call it manually. Do you have an idea ?

I still tried something like this :

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject) {
    if checkLog == true
    {
     //finish   
    }
    else
   {
    // undo
   }
}

@IBAction func ConexTAP(sender: UIButton)
{
 //check login
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do the credentials check in the following method in your `ViewController`:

```
func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(_ identifier: String!,
                              sender: AnyObject!) -> Bool
```

In alternative, you can bind the `UIButton` to an action in your view controller, perform the checks here and then trigger a segue by code.

Comment: Thanks it work ! Could you show me how to trigger a segue by code ?

Comment: Use `performSegueWithIdentifier("segueName", sender: self)`

Comment: @mxb Taking your approach, would you still create (control+drag) the segue "segueName" on Storyboard, from the button to next scene? If so, is the segue going to be automatically fired upon button click, without checking the credentials?

Answer (score 7):

In Swift you can proceed by:

Step 1: Insert a segue from ViewControllerA to ViewControllerB. The segue should start from ViewControllerA itself and not from any control (like Button).

Step 2: Give segue an unique identifier in storyboard. Ex: seageFromAtoB

Step 3 : In your ViewControllerforA.swift write :

```
if(condition == true) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("seageFromAtoB", sender: self)
}
```

If you are performing some task in some other Thread then using performSegueWithIdentifier can throw an exception.

If you get this error then you should use :

```
if(condition==true){
      NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {
           self.performSegueWithIdentifier("seageFromAtoB", sender: self)
      }
}
```

This will perform segue from ViewControllerA to ViewControllerB with a specific condition.